# Flutter Wrote stack traces to tombstoned

Tags: flutter, socket.io

I keep getting these errors where the app freezes and crashed.

How to reproduce:
Pop out of page that is using camera and socket_io_client.

Errors:

```
E/libc    ( 6226): Access denied finding property "net.dns1"
E/libc    ( 6226): Access denied finding property "net.dns2"
E/libc    ( 6226): Access denied finding property "net.dns3"
E/libc    ( 6226): Access denied finding property "net.dns4"
D/        ( 6226): PlayerBase::stop() from IPlayer
D/AudioTrack( 6226): stop(2735): called with 5082560 frames delivered
I/crowds.station( 6226): Thread[6,tid=6246,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0x7eaac55000,peer=0x13540320,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
I/crowds.station( 6226): 
D/TcpOptimizer( 6226): [tcpStateMonitor] poll() fail, ret=-1, nSockets=4, errno=4
I/crowds.station( 6226): Wrote stack traces to tombstoned
Lost connection to device.
```

Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: Hi, what version of flutter and camera package are you using? I'm also getting this. It intermittently happens when popping the camera overlay, after taking a photo, and only on Android. I think it might be isolated to the flutter camera package, and not socket.io

Answer (score 1):

The logs `Access denied finding property "net.dns"` is a low-level warning thrown in Android and isn't the cause of the app crashing - this is similarly mentioned on this [thread](https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Agora-Flutter-Quickstart/issues/41#issuecomment-624979308).

On the other hand, `signal 3` from the Signal Catcher indicates that the [app became unresponsive (ANR)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29777311). The crash occurred in a low-level code resulting for the stack trace be written in tombstone. You might need to [extract the logs dumped from tombstone](https://source.android.com/docs/core/tests/debug) to identify the culprit of the issue.